# How to Find an Element by Attribute in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I have a variable containing the list of selects, then I'd need to filter and find only those that has dependsOn attribute with the value of 'EventType'.

I tried the below but it doesn't find the select and returns 0:

```
var selects = $("select");
var count = selects.find("[dependsOn='EventType']").length
alert(count);
```

I wrote the below which works but isn't there an easier way?

```
var dependents = [];
        selectLists.each(function() {

            var dep = $(this).attr('dependsOn');
            if (dep === undefined) return;

            dependents.push(dep.val());
        });
```

Comment: Could you post your html?

Comment: missing `;` after `.....length`

Comment: `alert($("select[dependsOn=EventType]").length);` works?

Answer (score 5):

If that attribute is on the actual `select` tag, just do:

```
var selects = $("select[dependsOn='EventType']");
```

Although, `dependsOn` doesn't seem like a valid attribute. Check out custom `data-*` attributes to have completely valid HTML.

Answer (score 3):

See [the documentation for find](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

> Get the **descendants** of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

You want to use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
selects.filter("[dependsOn='EventType']").length
```

Alternatively, just put the condition in your initial selector:

```
$("select[dependsOn='EventType']").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `data` attribute

then you can do:

```
var selects = $("select");
selects.find('[data-dependsOn="EventType"]').length;
alert(count);
```

`find()` is used to select the child elements, if you want to target `select` element, you can use:

```
var selects = $('select[data-dependsOn="EventType"]').length;
alert(count);
```

Comment: @TheLight Make sure in your HTML markup your `select` element has this attribute `data-dependsOn="EventType"`

Answer (score 0):

try with you'r browser's console (I'm using chrome) and use this:

```
selects = $("select[dependsOn='EventType']");
```

It worked just fine for me.
Hope it helps!!